# Sort a List by a property and then by another

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, sorting

I have an example class containing two data points:

```
public enum Sort { First, Second, Third, Fourth }
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(Sort sort, string name) { 
        this.Sort = sort; 
        this.Name = name; 
    }

    public Sort Sort { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm looking to sort them into groups by their `Sort` property, and then alphabetize those groups.

```
List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>() { 
    new MyClass(MyClass.Sort.Third, "B"), 
    new MyClass(MyClass.Sort.First, "D"),
    new MyClass(MyClass.Sort.First, "A"),
    new MyClass(MyClass.Sort.Fourth, "C"),
    new MyClass(MyClass.Sort.First, "AB"),
    new MyClass(MyClass.Sort.Second, "Z"),
};
```

The output would then be:
(showing `Name`)

```
A
AB
D
Z
B
C
```

I've been able to do this by using a `foreach` to separate the items into many smaller arrays (grouped by the enum value) but this seems very tedious - and I think there must be some LINQ solution that I don't know about.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using extension methods, first `OrderBy` the enum, `ThenBy` name.

```
var sorted = list.OrderBy( m => m.Sort ).ThenBy( m => m.Name );
```

Answer (score 5):

Aside from the nice LINQ solutions, you can also do this with a compare method like you mentioned. Make `MyClass` implement the `IComparable` interface, with a `CompareTo` method like:

```
  public int CompareTo(object obj)
  {
      MyClass other = (MyClass)obj;
      int sort = this.srt.CompareTo(other.srt);
      return (sort == 0) ? this.Name.CompareTo(other.Name) : sort;
  }
```

The above method will order your objects first by the enum, and if the enum values are equal, it compares the name. Then, just call `list.Sort()` and it will output the correct order.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it, I think

```
var result = from m in list
             orderby m.Sort, m.Name
             select m;
```

Comment: This syntax is not valid. The `select m` needs to be placed at the end, then it'll be correct.