# Order list by special enum value in linq

Tags: c#, linq, enums

i want to order my list according to below picture
(first field is int and second is an Enum)

i want to records with "foo" value comes at first of output

how can i do this in c# and linq?

thanks in advance

```
public enum myEnum{
    goo,
    foo,
    boo
}
```

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a List<?> by an enum, and then by alphabetical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414183/sort-a-list-by-an-enum-and-then-by-alphabetical)

Comment: You should not rely on the order of enum values, especially if you don't assign a number manually. Someone else (or you) might think later that reordering these enums shouldn't cause any side effects, but it will. Instead i also suggest Dmitry's dictionary.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For *arbitrary* enum and sort order e.g.

```
  public enum MyEnum {
    boo = -1,
    foo = 3, 
    goo = 154,    
  };
```

I suggest *mapping*:

```
  // we want foo, boo, goo order
  internal static readonly Dictionary<MyEnum, int> enumOrder = 
    new  Dictionary<MyEnum, int>() {
      {MyEnum.foo, 1},
      {MyEnum.boo, 2},
      {MyEnum.goo, 3},
  };
```

Query:

```
  var result = source
    .OrderBy(item => enumOrder[item.SecondField]) // map second field on the desired order
    .ThenBy(item => item.FirstField);
```

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Thank you, `EnumOrder` is indeed more readable

Comment: @Ali7091: yes, as it's shown in the question, `foo` should be the first (followed by `boo` and then `goo` in that order).

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Quite right, thank you, but I'd rather change `public` into `internal` (or `private`)

Comment: This wont work with SQL.

Answer (score 5):

A simpler approach is to just evaluate the enum and return comparison value:

```
 var result = list.OrderBy(item => item.myEnum == myEnum.foo ? 1 : 2)
                  .ThenBy(item => item.myEnum == myEnum.boo ? 1 : 2)
                  .ThenBy(item => item.myEnum == myEnum.goo ? 1 : 2);
```

This way you won't need extra variables and a more readable code.

Sample: https://repl.it/repls/CornsilkGiganticDevelopers

Answer (score 3):

The below code will sort `yourData` by two properties - `NameOfYourEnumPropertyHere` and `NameOfYourIntPropertyHere`. You need to replace with your property names and away you go.

```
var sortedResult = yourData
    .OrderBy(z => z.NameOfYourEnumPropertyHere)
    .ThenBy(z => z.NameOfYourIntPropertyHere).ToList();
```

Comment: You will notice that you changed the question after I posted my answer. In your earlier revision, the order of the enum entries was different.

Comment: yes i changed my enum order ,please answer with this enum structure

Comment: @Ali7091 With your edited enum, you should go with Dmitry's solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found this reasonably simple as well:

```
var result = list.OrderBy(item => item.myEnum == myEnum.foo)
              .ThenBy(item => item.myEnum == myEnum.boo)
              .ThenBy(item => item.myEnum == myEnum.goo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible updates to the Enum should be surfaced with a `NotImplementedException`. Which is easier to add if a function is used instead of the dictionary method @Dmitry mentioned.

```
private int SortOrderOf(myEnum enumValue)
{
    switch (enumValue)
    {
        case myEnum.foo: return 1;
        case myEnum.boo: return 2;
        case myEnum.goo: return 3;
        default: throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var result = source
.OrderBy(item => SortOrderOf(item.SecondField)) // rely on SortOrderOf() to determine order of second field
.ThenBy(item => item.FirstField);
```

Using a function also allows for overloading with the same name. `SortOrderOf()` can be used for both `myEnum` and `myEnumTwo`. With a mapping dictionary different variable names would need to be used.

Answer (score -1):

```cs
var collection = new List<myCustomObjectWithEnumProperty>();
var sortedCollection = collection.OrderBy(c=>(int)c.EnumProperty);
```

To see:
https://cmatskas.com/ordering-enums-with-c/

My Code:

```cs
public enum TicketPriorityEnum
{
    Düşük = 0,
    Normal = 1,
    Yüksek = 2,
}

if (priority == "3")
    d = d.OrderBy(x => (int)x.TicketPriority).ThenByDescending(x => x.Id);

if (priority == "4")
    d = d.OrderByDescending(x => (int)x.TicketPriority).ThenByDescending(x => x.Id);
```

Comment: Please use the code of the question when answering. Also, when posting a new answer to an old, well answered question, explain how your answers complements exiting answers. Also, pay attention to code formatting.  That said, your answer isn't even correct. This doesn't order a specific enum value as first. You never get all "Normals" sorted first if that's required.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).